# adding columns and filling based on date

Tags: r, dataframe

```r
mydata <- data.frame(co = c(2.3,3.1,5.7), b = c(3,5,6), mydate = c(as.Date ("2015-10-01"), as.Date ("2015-11-01"), as.Date ("2015-12-01")))
```

I would like to add and fill columns based on a date.
I want the final output to look something like this:

```
  co  b     mydate m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9 m10 m11 m12                                         
1 2.3 3 2015-10-01  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0                                                  
2 3.1 5 2015-11-01  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0                                                  
3 5.7 6 2015-12-01  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1
```

Comment: GrBa, please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189 for how to format code and data in questions. Namely (though _there is more_), use code-fences `\`\`\`` on lines of their own before and after blocks of code; this formats it differently and (subjectively) it looks/flows more easily within the question. DarrenTsai has suggested an edit (twice now) that does this; no further change is required _now_, but if you wipe their edit again, please shift to using the code-fences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both, I add a `for` loop that adds the missing months; if your real data is full-enough (all months are included), then you may not need it (or may not care even if a month is missing).

Note: (I missed this the first time) `format(.., format="%m")` will zero-pad the months. I prefer zero-padded personally (for many reasons, including that it sorts correctly), but if you don't want that, then replace `format(...)` with `sub("^m0", "m", format(...))`.

### base R (and reshape2)

```r
out <- mydata |>
  transform(m = format(mydate, format = "m%m"), v = 1L) |>
  reshape2::dcast(formula = co + b + mydate ~ m, value.var = "v", fill = 0L)
for (col in paste0("m", 1:12)) if (!col %in% names(out)) out[[col]] <- 0L
out
#    co b     mydate m10 m11 m12 m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9
# 1 2.3 3 2015-10-01   1   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 2 3.1 5 2015-11-01   0   1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 3 5.7 6 2015-12-01   0   0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
out <- mydata %>%
  mutate(m = format(mydate, format = "m%m"), v = 1L) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(c(co, b, mydate), names_from = "m", values_from = "v", values_fill = 0L)
for (col in paste0("m", 1:12)) if (!col %in% names(out)) out[[col]] <- 0L
out
# # A tibble: 3 x 15
#      co     b mydate       m10   m11   m12    m1    m2    m3    m4    m5    m6    m7    m8    m9
#   <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1   2.3     3 2015-10-01     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 2   3.1     5 2015-11-01     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 3   5.7     6 2015-12-01     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Big thanks. A very helpful answer.
It's just aesthetics and the desire to learn more. Is it possible to arrange the columns m1 - 12?

Comment: `dplyr::select` lets you choose them manually. One issue is that they will sort lexicographically, which means `"m1", "m10", "m11", "m12", "m2", ...`. Since I don't like to assume columns are exactly as questions show them, a general way to move all month-columns into the right order and at the "right" of the frame: `out <- out[,c(setdiff(names(out), paste0("m", 1:12)), paste0("m", 1:12))]`

Comment: `> out
# A tibble: 68 x 16
      co     a     b mydate       m10   m11   m12   m01   m02   m03   m04
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1  1.74     1    10 2015-10-01     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2  6.49     1    11 2015-11-01     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 3 10.1      1    12 2015-12-01     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 4 16.3      1    13 2016-01-01     0     0     0     1     0     0     0`

m01, m02 ... 0 is a problem

Comment: Right. See my edit, use `sub("^m0", "m", format(mydate, format="m%m"))`.